# Illustrator - How to change the color of the line between two anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

How can I change the color of the (anchor handle and path) lines that illustrator shows between two points?

Example:

[image]

In my case, the line is black and it's impossible to see if I'm working with a black background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those lines will be whatever color you have selected for your layer.

If your layer color is black, then those will also be black.

---

Just change the color of your layer by *double clicking* on the layer and selecting a different color.

To open the Layers Panel, go to **Window → Layer** or hit <kbd>F7</kbd>

[image]

There is a list of colors to choose from, but if you'd like you can also select *custom* and choose any color you want.